# Bash, execute command after invoking a new shell

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I am trying to make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -s
something...
```

When I execute it, I get a new shell but `something` is executed only when I exit the shell created by `sudo -s`, not inside it.

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `sudo -s` without any argument will open an interactive shell for root.

If you just want to run a single command using `sudo -s`, you can simple do:

```
sudo -s command
```

For example :

```
$ sudo -s whoami
root
```

Or you can use here strings :

```
$ sudo -s <<<'whoami'
root
```

If you have multiple commands you can use here doc :

```
$ sudo -s <<'EOF'
> whoami
> hostname
> EOF
root
something--
```

Comment: It is not good to use `sudo -s` just in case the `root` user had the (rather poor) idea to change its shell. This should really be `sudo sh` which explicitly states which shell is to be used.

Answer (score 9):

Another way would be to pass a full bash command(s) to `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo bash -c 'command1; command2; command3;'
```

However, a better way would be to launch the *script* with `sudo` instead. It is not a very good idea to have `sudo` inside the script. Far better to run the entire script with root privileges (`sudo script.sh`). If necessary, you can use `sudo` to drop privileges for specific commands. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
whoami
echo $HOME
sudo -u terdon whoami  ## drop privileges for specific command.
```

Running the script above returns:

```
$ sudo ~/scripts/a.sh
root
/root
terdon
```

Answer (score 3):

The **Bourne shell** has a `-c` flag which you can use to pass an arbitrary script to the shell, so that you can write something like

```
sudo sh -c 'something'
```

This is however only useful for the simplest commands, because it is very cumbersome to quote the script correctly and the inconvenience is even higher if you send the command to a remote server over **ssh** because the argument script will be analysed twice, once on the side sending the script and once on the side running the script.

If `something` is a complex script or needs to be passed over a **ssh** line, it is common practice to write a function `prepare_something_script` whose job is to write the script 'something' on *stdout*. In its simplest form, this function can use a here-document to generate its output:

```
prepare_something_script()
{
  cat <<EOF
something
EOF
}
```

The script produced by `prepare_something_script` can then be executed locally with the privileges granted by **sudo** as follows:

```
prepare_something_script | sudo sh
```

In the scenario where the script must be executed remotely with privileges granted by **sudo** it is customary to encode the script in base 64 to avoid redirecting the standard input of **ssh**, like this:

```
something64=$(prepare_something_script | base64)
ssh usesr@remote-host "echo ${something64} | base64 --decode | sudo sh"
```

If you use that code in a function, do not forget to mark the *something64* variable as *local*. Some implementations of **base64** offer a `-d` flag to decode, which is less well supported than the verbose `--decode` variant. Some implementations require to add a `-w 0` to the encoding command to avoid spurious line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the command ahead of sudo -s, instead of in the next line.

```
sudo -s something...
```